# Magento 1.9.X.X allignment problem

Tags: magento-1.9

enter image d[image]escription here

[image]

[image]

Hey Guys! I am new to magento and after installing a theme  what happens is in the product catalog grid the products are not alligned and in the product page the add to cart and other options go down instead of right after the image. But when I minimize the window it looks fine. See the images for reference. The first image every product on the grid have add to cart not aligned. It is sever when the price is 4 digit and after the offer price it goes down. The second and third image have also allignment problem. Please help!